# angularjs ng-repeat on a element with ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs for my app, where I have

```
$scope.columns = [
                                        {
                                          "displayName": "Column A",
                                          "selected": true,
                                          "sortable": true
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "displayName": "Column B",
                                          "selected": true,
                                          "sortable": false
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "displayName": "Column C",
                                          "selected": true,
                                          "sortable": true
                                        }
                             ];
```

Based on this, I am rendering columns in a table in markup.

```
<table>
    <thead>
          <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-if="column.selected && column.sortable" ng-click="toggleSort(column.name)" class="sortable"
                            ng-class="{sorting_desc:sortBy===column.name &amp;&amp; sortOrder==='DESC',
                                       sorting_asc:sortBy===column.name &amp;&amp; sortOrder==='ASC'
                                      }">
                            {{column.displayName}}
                        </th>
                        <th ng-repeat="column in columnSettings" ng-if="column.selected && !column.sortable">
                            {{column.displayName}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

So, basically, I want to do

```
  if column is selectable 
       check if sortable 
               apply ng-class and ng-click on td element.
             else
               render normal td element
```

Above code works but it first renders all sortable columns and then non-sortable columns.

Eg:  it renders
     Column A   Column C   Column B

but I want it to render
     Column A   Column B   Column C

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I finally had a solution and here is it.

```
<th ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-if="column.selected"
                                 ng-click="column.sortable && toggleSort(column.name)"
                                    ng-class="{sorting_desc:sortField===column.name &amp;&amp; sortOrder==='DESC' &amp;&amp; column.sortable,
                                    sorting_asc:sortField===column.name &amp;&amp; sortOrder==='ASC' &amp;&amp; column.sortable,
                                    sortable: column.sortable}"
                                    >
                                {{column.displayName}}
                        </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making each `th` into a separate repeating block, you could use `ng-repeat-start` on the first `th` and `ng-repeat-end` on the second to group both elements into a single repeating sequence.

```
<table>
    <thead>
          <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat-start="column in columns" ng-if="column.selected && column.sortable" ng-click="toggleSort(column.name)" class="sortable"
                            ng-class="{sorting_desc:sortBy===column.name &amp;&amp; sortOrder==='DESC',
                                       sorting_asc:sortBy===column.name &amp;&amp; sortOrder==='ASC'
                                      }">
                            {{column.displayName}}
                        </th>
                        <th ng-repeat-end ng-if="column.selected && !column.sortable">
                            {{column.displayName}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it now renders                                                                 Column A Column B Column B Column C                                                          Column B is rendered twice... one with sort feature and another one without sort feature.

Answer (score 0):

Using additional intermediate element is more clean

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="column in columns">

                    <div class="sortable"
                    ng-if="column.selected && column.sortable"                    
                    ng-click="toggleSort(column.displayName)">
                        {{column.displayName}}
                    </div>

                    <div ng-if="column.selected && !column.sortable">
                        {{column.displayName}}
                    </div>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```